# How do you fast forward or rewind audio (like a song) for a certain time interval with AV Audio Player in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer

I need help using AV Audio Player, a Swift tool I'm not very familiar with. I need to know how to fast forward and/or rewind audio time with AV Audio Player in Swift 5. There is a currentTime() property for AV Audio Player that may be helpful in doing this, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: Set the AVAudioPlayer's `currentTime`. It measures the position (time) within the song, in seconds. (It calls this a TimeInterval, but that's just a Double signifying seconds or a fraction thereof.)

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1387297-currenttime) remarks:

> By setting this property you can seek to a specific point in a sound file or implement audio fast-forward and rewind functions.